# Using standalone methods for each scene in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, methods, scene, stage

I'm trying to use my scene, `home`, as a scene in `start`.
However it does not work and instead of getting my 300 x 300, I get a blank 900 x 400 screen. Perhaps it's something very easily detectable but I'm not seeing it?

```
    private Scene home;
    private Stage window;    

    public Scene home(Scene home) {
        // build my scene
        return home = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
    } 

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setScene(home);
        window.show();
    }
```

I'm trying to create my scenes as methods so I can keep them out of `start`.
The plan is to switch between scenes later by using: `btn.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(anotherScene));`, thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call the `home` method. Therefore the `home` field will remain `null` which is the value you pass to `window.setScene`.

Furthermore I'd call the `home` method is implemented in a strange way:

```
public Scene home(Scene home) {
```

The parameter is never read.

```
    return home = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
```

This assigns the value to **the method parameter**, not to the scene before it returns the scene, which has no effect, since java is call-by-value.

You could implement it like this:

```
private Scene home;
private Stage window;    

public Scene home() {
    if (home == null) {
        // build my scene
        home = new Scene(root, 300, 300)

        // or maybe do this without testing, if the scene was created before???
    }
    return home;
} 

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    window = primaryStage;
    window.setScene(home()); // use the method here
    window.show();
}
```